# Is there a way to add a subscription to a PayPal purchase AFTER initial checkout?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

We sell online training courses, so our product is completely digital. We have found that our conversion rate is much better if have users go through the standard checkout process, and THEN, on the confirmation page, ask if they want to sign up for auto-renewal. The way we achieve that now is to essentially enroll everyone in the subscription plan at checkout, but then if they choose to not accept auto-renewal, we cancel the subscription while keeping the initial one-time payment. This isn't ideal, and more often than not the user will get an email congratulating them on their subscription purchase prior to them opting out of auto-renewal. This causes a fair amount of confusion and support calls.

QUESTION: Is there a way to have our standard checkout on one page where users fill out billing details for a one-time purchase and then, on a different page (confirmation page) allow them to select auto-renewal (subscription) WITHOUT having to resubmit billing information? I thought maybe the Smart Buttons might work, setting the "intent" to "authorize" and then on the confirmation page, dynamically changing things prior to sending to PayPal, but it doesn't seem to function like I had anticipated. Maybe I'm missing something?

I guess what I'm really saying is...

Is there a way to modify an order after it has been purchased. I.e. adding a yearly subscription on to the original order after the user's consent to do so? Any code examples? I had this set up on Stripe in no time, but I can't seem to find a way to do it with PayPal.

As for site details, we are using Wordpress with the Paid Memberships Pro plugin. All coding is done using PHP, Javascript and jQuery.

Thanks in advance for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have the user approve the subscription (which will charge the `setup_fee` immediately) yet not activate it on approval -- only activate it on your review page if they accept the auto-renewal.

To do this, when you [create the subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body), set an `application_context` object with `"user_action": "CONTINUE"`.

If they accept the auto-renewal, [activate the subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_activate).